# Java operator precedence

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I was playing around with java code, until I hit this hard wall:

```
int m = 5;
            System.out.println(m++);
            System.out.println(++m);
            System.out.println(m = ++m * 2);
            System.out.println(m = m++ * 2);

            System.out.println(m);
```

and the output ( which I really can't explain) is as follows:

```
5
7
16
32
32
```

This is really driving me crazy ! Why is the compiler skipping the last m++ before multiplication ? is it that the compiler adds 1 to another instance of m than the original ... I really doubt even that does make any sense at all!

Comment: Never use `m++` within the expression which is assigned to `m` and you won't be having problems. Other than that, you just need to read up on the semantics of Java's expression evaluation, publicly available from Oracle (the Java Language Specification).

Comment: m++ is post increment, and after it increments, but before it's ever used, you overwrite it with the result of a calculation which used its old value.

Comment: This would be an undefined behavior in C++. I guess this means you shouldn't do it anywhere.

Comment: @JanDvorak you sure? It looks well-defined to me (though I agree it should never be used)

Comment: @Dave the write-back to `m` from the post-increment is unsequenced with the write-back to `m` from the explicit assignment. Thus, UB.

Comment: There's no practical reason for this code guys, I was just testing out operator precedence and .. well, I got here :) Thanks to all of you guys.

Comment: Java uses a more strict ordering of operations than the C languages.  The `=` assignment will always be the last operation, so the modification caused by `m++` is overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

Java performs `=` last so if you do

```
m = m++;
```

you are actually doing

```
int tmp = m;
m++;
m = tmp;
```

Which is just a great way to confuse yourself, so don't do it. ;)

---

However, if you like confusing yourself, you could go all out and write code like this.

```
for (char c⁯‮h = 0; c⁯‮h < Character.MAX_VALUE; c⁯‮h++)
    if (Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(c⁯‮h) && !Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(c⁯‮h))
        System.out.printf("%04x <%s>%n", (int) c⁯‮h, "" + c⁯‮h);
```

which doesn't even look like it compiles, but it does. It prints all the non-ascii characters you can use in Java identifiers.

Comment: I can't believe my eyes, when I paste that into my editor it changes...how is that happening?

Comment: @pinkpanther The trick is in the Unicode special character which makes the text flow right-to-left.

Comment: @pinkpanther For an explaination http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/hidden-code.html In short there is a character `\u202e` which you can use in identifiers which causes the rest of the line to be printed backwards (and is zero width as a bonus)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik all the brackets are flipped to make it more readable (if you are reading right to left)

Comment: All hail to Eclipse, I managed to unscramble it with "Rename in file" applied to `ch` :)